# How to Display Chosen Image in Image Source

Tags: angularjs

I would like to show when a file is selected, in the `input`. Why isn't it showing? My code:

```
<input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" ng-model="service.logo" required="required">
<img ng-src="{{service.logo}}">
```

[Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5ofwvhn6/17/)

Comment: have a look at this stackoverflow answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347656/angularjs-show-image-preview-only-if-selected-file-is-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the only thing that gets passed to `value` and thus `ng-model` of a `file input` is the file name

If you want a preview (before upload) you need to use `FileReader API` to read the file and parse it into a data url and pass that to an image element

Answer (score 2):

Because in this you are just taking the input from the user. You need to write code to open the file, read it and display on to the view. As you want to show the image when the user browses and selects it, you need to trigger the fileSelect.
Also, look into this, I think this is what you want. [How to read a file in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839048/how-to-read-a-file-in-angularjs)